# How to force browser to refresh view in middle of long process

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to force browser to show the real process for every iterate, as in this code:

```js
document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "new HTML"
for (let i = 0; i < 334339; i++) {
  document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "new HTML" + i;
  document.getElementById("dd").width=40;
}
```

```html
<div id="dd">
  xxxxxxx
</div>
<div id="ss">
  <input type="button"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: You could use a setTimeout, but there's not use for this. Since you always overwrite the innerHTML, setting `document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "new HTML 334338"; will have the same effect. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Do you try to build a loading bar? or anything else?

Comment: just to be clear, as you already got answers, it doesn't work currently as iit is in your question because all the javascript is executed, and only *then* the browser refresh the page. As Javascript is basically single-threaded, you must "let go" of your execution if you want to see an intermediate result. One way of achieving that is to use asynchronous programming with events and callbacks, as with `setInterval`

Comment: interesting video on the way Javascript works : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Yes, I saw above Youtube link before couple weeks. This is some example of basic knowledge about the event loop, that forgotten after two decade of buzzwords and patterns. But under hood all work with fetching loop and callback. We knew it well from the first Graphic OS (like Window 1, 1985)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval` to achieve this. The first argument of `setInterval` is the function to call (the code to run every loop), and the second argument is how often you want that function to be called (in milliseconds)

See example below:

```js
document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "new HTML"

let i = 0;
let loop = setInterval(function() {
  if(i >= 15) { // change to something smaller to see it stop
    clearInterval(loop);
  }
  document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "new HTML" + i;
  document.getElementById("dd").width=40;
  
  i++;
}, 100) // call the setInterval function every 100m/s
```

```html
<div id="dd"></div>
```

If you wish to stop the loop eventually you can then use `clearInterval()` to stop the callback from running continuously

Comment: Basically I not understand why Browser not support force redrew from in JS code. I wonder how Progress bar work. If i understand, I must separate my iterate every place I need it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `setInterval` is the best option for your case.

```js
document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "new HTML"

let i = 0;
let stop = 334339;
let time_millis = 200;

let int = setInterval(function() {
  document.getElementById("dd").innerHTML = "new HTML" + i;
  document.getElementById("dd").width=40;
  i++;
  if (i == stop) clearInterval(int);
}, time_millis);
```

```html
<div id="dd">
  xxxxxxx
</div>
<div id="ss">
  <input type="button"></input>
</div>
```